# Can you make complaints about the way the system works?

Tags: support

Ok so I disagree with the way a certain part of the system works but I can't find anything that will let me complain or flag what I consider abuse of said system to a moderator.

Is there even such a thing as a generic "I want to speak to a moderator please."?

Comment: Must it be private?

Comment: When you've got an entire community proud of what they've done (and rightly so, don't get me wrong) you get apathy towards problems. The fact that there is no place to make private complaints that actually get acted upon is slightly disappointing.

Comment: @Sean Why complain privately? This site/network is largely run by us, the community. Discuss it with the community. You win some, you lose some. If there is a problem affecting the community as a whole, discuss it with us. If there is a problem or abuse happening that only a moderator can handle, by all means flag. But that's not the case here, from what I gather.

Comment: @Bart Yeah perhaps I'm in the wrong place then because that way of running things really irks me. Nothing ever gets done that way in my experience. I'm not inclined to wait x months to see if anything is done about it either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got to the place to do just so - Meta is for discussing the system.

If you do have an issue with some aspect of the site/system, this is the place to post it.

Do search first to see if this has already been brought up and discussed and to see why things may be the way they are.

Comment: @Sean: Since you're going to talk openly about this issue anyway, **just freaking post it already** instead of going off on a tangent here. No need to contact the mods or whatever either.